# Evaluate $\int \left(\frac{\ln x}{x^2-x\ln x}\right)^2(\ln x-1)\, dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $$\int \left(\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-x\ln(x)}\right)^2(\ln(x)-1)\, dx$$

Now, my attempt was to a add and substract $+1$ and $-1$ like this : $\int (\frac{lnx-1+1}{x^2-xlnx})^2(lnx-1) dx$ . Then,  $\int (\frac{lnx-1}{x^2-xlnx}+\frac{1}{x^2-xlnx})^2(lnx-1) dx$ and $2\int \frac{lnx-1}{(x^2-xlnx)^2} dx$ (I've tried to make it look simpler) but I am getting stuck . Any other ideas will be appreciated ! ( wolfram gives an ugly result )

Comment: The substitution $\frac{1}{x}=t$ is obvious for me to do first, then try $t\ln t =y$ to arrive at something that you should be able to finish.

Comment: Thank you ! My thought at first, was to try to get rid of that product in the beginning .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note

$$\begin{align}
&\int \left(\frac{\ln x}{x^2-x\ln x}\right)^2(\ln x-1)\, dx\\
=&\int \left(\frac{\frac{\ln x}x}{1-\frac{\ln x}x}\right)^2\frac{\ln x-1}{x^2}\, dx\\
=&-\int \frac{ \left(\frac{\ln x}x\right)^2  }{\left(1-\frac{\ln x}x\right)^2}d(\frac{\ln x}{x})\\ 
=&-\int \frac{t^2}{(1-t)^2}dt\\ 
\end{align}$$
where $t=\frac{\ln x}x$.